# Error de incompatibilidad de datos al regresar a una vista principal en ASP.Net MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Estoy tratando de crear un nuevo cliente, en caso de que lo haga exitosamente, debe regresar a la pantalla principal en donde estan todos los clientes. Pero al intentar hacerlo me salta la pantalla de error con el siguiente error

> El elemento de modelo pasado al diccionario es de tipo 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[SegurosDeVida.Models.DTO_Cliente]', pero este diccionario requiere un elemento de modelo de tipo 'SegurosDeVida.Models.DTO_Cliente'.

Este es el codigo de la vista create, la cual utilizo para crear el nuevo cliente:

```
@model SegurosDeVida.Models.DTO_Cliente

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Create</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Cliente"))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>DTO_Cliente</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Identificacion, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Identificacion, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Identificacion, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Nombre, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Nombre, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Nombre, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Apellido, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Apellido, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Apellido, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Edad, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Edad, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Edad, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Volver Atras", "Index","Cliente")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Este es el codigo de la vista principal

```
@model IEnumerable<SegurosDeVida.Models.DTO_Cliente>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Nuevo Cliente", "Create","Cliente")>   
</p>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            Numero de Cliente
        </th>
        <th>
            Identificacion
        </th>
        <th>
            Nombre
        </th>
        <th>
            Apellido
        </th>
        <th>
            Edad
        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IdCliente)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Identificacion)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Nombre)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Apellido)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Edad)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.ActionLink("Editar", "Edit", "Cliente") |
                @Html.ActionLink("Eliminar", "Delete", "Cliente") |
            </td>
            </tr>
        }

    </table>
```

Este es el codigo del controlador cliente, el cual utilizo para cargar los clientes en la pantalla principal, asi como crear nuevos clientes:

```
namespace SegurosDeVida.Controllers
{
    public class ClienteController : Controller
    {
        ServiceCliente service = null;
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            service = new ServiceCliente();
            return View(service.GetClientes(true));
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            service = new ServiceCliente();
            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(string Identificacion, string Nombre, string Apellido, string Edad)
        {
            service = new ServiceCliente();
            bool exito;
            DTO_Cliente dto = new DTO_Cliente();
            DTO_Atributos dtoa = new DTO_Atributos();
            IList<DTO_Atributos> lista = new List<DTO_Atributos>();

            dtoa.IdAtributo = "1";
            dtoa.Titulo = "Maneja";
            dtoa.Valor = false;
            dtoa.Observaciones = "nada";

            lista.Add(dtoa);

            dtoa.IdAtributo = "2";
            dtoa.Titulo = "Usa Lentes";
            dtoa.Valor = false;
            dtoa.Observaciones = "nada";

            lista.Add(dtoa);

            dto.Identificacion = Identificacion;
            dto.Nombre = Nombre;
            dto.Apellido = Apellido;
            dto.Edad = Edad;
            dto.Activo = true;

            exito = service.RegistrarCliente(dto,lista);

            if (exito)
            {
                ViewBag.res = "Clientes registrado con exito";
                ViewBag.Alerta = "Success";
            }  
            else
            {
                ViewBag.res = "Error al registrar el cliente, intenten nuevamente";
                ViewBag.Alerta = "Danger";
            }
            return Index();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Delete(string IdCliente)
        {
            service = new ServiceCliente();
            service.EliminarCliente(Convert.ToInt32(IdCliente));
            return Index();
        }
        
         
        }
}
```

Como se observa, al registrar el nuevo cliente, llamo al `Index()`, el cual, llama a un `service.GetClientes(true))` que devuelve una IList<DTO_Cliente>. Cuando cargo la pantalla principal, me trae los clientes sin problemas como se observa:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero al llamar al `Index()`, desde la vista de creación, me arroja el error antes mencionado. Les agradeceria me indicaran donde esta mi error, seguramente es alguna tontera, pero estoy iniciándome en ASP.Net y no veo donde esta el error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El retorno del Action **Create** no es correcto ya que estás retornando lo que genere la vista *Index* en la vista *Create* (Index genera una lista de SegurosDeVida.Models.DTO_Cliente y Create espera solamente un SegurosDeVida.Models.DTO_Cliente)

Probá cambiarlo por un redirect:

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Cliente");
```